# After installing KDE Plasma, the default file manager became dolphin for browsers on Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde, nautilus, pop-os

I installed and then removed KDE Plasma on my POP OS 20.04 LTS and since then in browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Chromium and Brave) it opens downloaded files with Dolphin.

The only solution founded is to uninstall Dolphin.

Even on a fresh created user, Dolphin is the default file manager for browsers.

Yet I get this result:

```
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

I would like to test KDE Plasma but I need to keep an usable Gnome session.

What is strange is, when I log in (in gnome), Nautilus is the default file manager for the browser, but after a short while it becomes Dolphin.

Like there is a process changing it.

What should I check?

**EDIT**
I did a fresh install in a VM of Pop OS 20.04 and I did `sudo apt install kde-standard`  as explained in https://support.system76.com/articles/desktop-environment/

And I get this strange behavior whereas I never logged in in KDE.