# Chrome still opens Nautilus in spite changing the default file manager to Dolphin in Pop!_OS

Tags: chrome, nautilus, file-manager, pop-os, defaults

Recently, I changed my default file manager from Nautilus to Dolphin in Pop!_OS by this command:

```
xdg-mime default org.kde.dolphin.desktop inode/directory'
```

and checked again which is the default file manager by executing this command:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

and I get this output:

```
org.kde.dolphin.desktop
```

But, Gogle Chrome still opens Nautilus as the default file manager. I thought of removing it, but doing so will result in potential damage to my system since it is a built-in file. Here is the picture to view the scenario.

[image]

And, instantly when I browsed that picture, Chrome, as usual, used Nautilus to browse the picture.

[image]

Anyway to sort out this issue? I just want to sure that all applications use Dolphin as the default file manager without removing Nautilus.

Update: As suggested, I also used `xdg-open` command to find the default file manager the system is using. And I noticed that, Dolphin opens up automatically with the entered file location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a directory in the default file manager and select a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364997/open-a-directory-in-the-default-file-manager-and-select-a-file)

Comment: actually no. Because executing xdg-open simply launches dolphin. I need to add something here. After executing xdg-open, qt5ct is automatically launched in the terminal. Let me give a sample output.  
`xdg-open /home/arkabhuiyan99/Pictures/`  
`qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin`  
`qt5ct: D-Bus global menu: no`

Comment: actually, the issue is with gtk file chooser. You need to replace it with kde file chooser(I don't know what is the exact name) or anything you want. Sadly, I could not find any working solution to this issue. I tried almost all of them but could not solve my problem.

Comment: Somehow similar, but describing a sort of opposite issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/646460/315749

Comment: he had to install kde and I don't want to do it. I wish to stick to gnome offered by pop.

Comment: Have the same issue. `org.kde.dolphin.desktop` worked all the way, now after some updates in openSUSE gtk file manager opens for some reason. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a dolphin vs nautilus issue. It's a GTK+2 vs GTK+3 issue. Apps written for GTK+2 will use the familiar-looking Humanity-themed file selection dialog, while apps written for GTK+3 will use the alien, hollow-looking default theme for GTK+3.

Unfortunately, the only way to get a consistent UX is to use all GTK+2 apps, or switch to a Qt-based DE like LXQT or KDE.

[Original post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455747/how-can-i-make-all-applications-use-nemos-file-selection-dialog-instead-of-naut)